# Почему пули не отображаются в Game, но их видно на сцене

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

//спавн пули

```
public void Shoot()
{
  Instantiate(_projectile, _shootPoint.position, _shootPoint.rotation);
}
```

//разворот персонажа, вставил так как, пули не видно только когда смотрит вправо

```
protected void Reverse()
{
  if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 )
      transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
  else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
      transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: предполагаю что материал пули прозрачный с одной из сторон и именно этой стороной летит пуля по сцене

Comment: У снаряда и пола одинаковые `position.z`.

Comment: я удалил пол, пули все равно не видно. Пуля спавнится и на сцене отображается, но в самой игре невидимая.